# Adding IAM SSO Group to Sagemaker Studio

Tags: terraform-provider-aws, amazon-sagemaker

I am using [`aws_sagemaker_domain`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/sagemaker_domain) to create a Sagemaker domain.  I can also use [`aws_safemaker_user_profile`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/sagemaker_user_profile) to add individual users to the user profile list.

That part is not really valuable because if we assign a group under the "Groups" tab in the Management Console, any user within that group has a user profile created at app launch time.

The problem:  I can't find any way to add the group to the Sagemaker Domain other than through the Management Console.  I need to use Terraform, but I cannot even find any of the documentation within CloudFormation.

[Documentation followed to add the group via the Management Console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/domain-groups.html)

---

Working with an architect at AWS... it appears it may be true that it only can be added through the Management Console.  The architect is looking to verify that.  The architect seems to have seen this sort of thing so much that he read words that weren't in the document that he cited stating that it says it can only be done through Management Console.  The document does NOT say that, it just says to add it manually: [Onboard users to Amazon SageMaker Studio with Active Directory group-specific IAM roles](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/onboard-users-to-amazon-sagemaker-studio-with-active-directory-group-specific-iam-roles/).  For the record, this is so... no go words can be said about this.  If the group is added, there is no need to add the user profiles... they get created just-in-time if the user is a member of the group.  So, they recommend setting up all of these additional components to get around the fact that adding the group assignment is missing from the API... and then say to go ahead and manually add the group later... just so that it looks sane (at best, it provides some awareness that the users are somehow related to the group).

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a bug, not just in Terraform, but also CDK & cloudformation and other IAC providers. When you use the AWS console the association between sagemaker user-profile and SSO user happens automatically via some other API calls. But using IAC doesn't call those same API calls. Here are the same issues opened in GitHub

https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/23627
https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/1128

Comment: Those are unrelated.  The issue is that group assignment is not available through the API.

Answer (score 0):

There is API support now to add SSO groups to a SageMaker domain (see documentation here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/domain-groups.html#domain-groups-add). There also seems to be a corresponding application assignment Terraform resource here - https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ssoadmin_application_assignment

The only caveat as per the docs is that the domain has to be created after Oct 1, 2023. For older domains, you will need to do it manually through the console.